# How can I populate a DropDown with the contents of an Array in .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

This is probably super obvious, but I'm incredibly new at MVC (and C# in general) and I just can't figure it out.

I have a viewModel that holds several bits of data about a project, which is then displayed in a table on the view using @foreach.

I want to set up a filter so that only the data belonging to the specified project is shown. I've figured out how to do this with filter buttons by using @foreach to create a new filter button for every distinct ProjectName present in the viewModel:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-filter" data-target="all">All</button>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Select(s => s.ProjectName).Distinct().ToArray())
    {
        {<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-filter" data-target="@item">@item</button>}

    }
</div>
```

The actual filtering is done with Chosen and jQuery, which I'm find with, but I can't figure out to to transfer the data from creating buttons to filling a DropDown menu.

I don't want to fill the DropDown with EVERY available ProjectName because there's hundreds, I only want the ones that actually exist in the viewModel at the time the page is loaded.

All the tutorials and guides I've found online involve creating more viewModels and List<> classes, which I would rather avoid if possible.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I was trying to use HTML Helpers, but with Chosen you can just do it in a SELECT statement:

```
    <select class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;">
    <option data-target="all">All</option>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Select(s => s.ProjectName).Distinct().ToArray())
    { <option data-target="@item">@item</option>
    }
    </select>
```